# Opening Local File in Webbrowser

Tags: python, python-3.x

EDIT: This is not a duplicate as I have added `file://` as suggested and get the same result.

I need to open and view a directory in my web browser (Chromium on Ubuntu 16.04)

Currently trying this

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('file:///path/to/directory')
```

This is opening Nautilus rather than my web browser.

Also receiving this error message:

```
(nautilus:6220): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
```

Note: If I try to open  `www.google.com` within `webbrowser.open()` that works as expected.

So, question:

**How do I open the directory in webbrowser rather than Nautilus?**

Comment: @DawidDaveKosiński Not the case, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you access it directly in the browser?

Comment: @DawidDaveKosiński Yes, if I open Chromium and navigate to file:///path/to/directory I get the contents of /directory as required/expected.

Comment: How about running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` from that directory and then passing the url instead ? `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

Comment: @Himal That works - as in I can see the contents of the file in my webbrowser - but I need to do this without using a HTTP Server.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open) "Note that on some platforms, trying to open a filename using this function, may work and start the operating system’s associated program. However, this is neither supported nor portable."

Comment: @Himal So it's not possible? Just tested on Windows 7 with Python 3.6.3 and it opens the file explorer too, rather than the webbrowser.